# MySQL keep type in case statement

Tags: mysql

I have a field that changes based on some input:

```
SELECT 
    CASE input
      WHEN 1 THEN id
      WHEN 2 THEN created_at
      WHEN 3 THEN some_varchar_field
    END as test
FROM ...
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

If I were to order by this field any numeric field isn't sorted properly, I noticed that the order by doesn't keep the type of the field that was selected rather, as soon as there is a VARCHAR/DATETIME field it will return that type rather then keep the type of the column itself. I was just wondering if there was a way to keep the type of the record that was selected.

Edit: Casting field as an int `CAST(id as INT)` did not work
Putting the case statement in the order by did not work as well.

Comment: You say that query works? But return diferent datatype? Because you usually cant have a `CASE` with different datatypes. But this is MySQL so wont be surprise allow those weird things

Comment: Yep, the query itself works, but it doesn't order by correctly. And yes, mysql does some weird things.

Comment: can you prepare a working sample on sqlFiddle?

Comment: I have never used sqlFiddle before, so I am not sure if this will work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9455c/4

Comment: I dont think you cant keep the type, looks like mySQL convert everything to the more generic type to hold every datatype on this case `varchar`. But if you want sort your result maybe you can use  User Variables. That is something you are interested to solve this question or you need the data type?

Comment: I don't need the data type, It is just the way to perform sorting properly. The main idea is the sort it correctly.

Comment: by the way check this example, change between 1 and 2 and see the result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb8ff/1

Comment: yep, and that is how I noticed that as soon as you add a varchar type or datetime, the sorting doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more research and testing, I was able to find a way to do it, a little bit 'cleaner'.

```
SELECT id, created_at, scomment
FROM test
ORDER BY 
  CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN id END ASC,
  CASE 1 WHEN 2 THEN created_at END ASC,
  CASE 1 WHEN 3 THEN scomment END ASC;
```

This will allow me to sort on a specific field correctly.
You could even add different directions by doing the following:

```
SELECT id, created_at, scomment
FROM test
ORDER BY 
  CASE p_order_by WHEN 1 THEN AND p_dir = 'asc' id END ASC,
  CASE p_order_by WHEN 1 THEN AND p_dir = 'desc' id END DESC,
  CASE p_order_by WHEN 2 THEN AND p_dir = 'asc' created_at END ASC,
  CASE p_order_by WHEN 2 THEN AND p_dir = 'desc' created_at END DESC,
  CASE p_order_by WHEN 3 THEN AND p_dir = 'asc' scomment END ASC,
  CASE p_order_by WHEN 3 THEN AND p_dir = 'desc' scomment END DESC;
```

Where p_order_by is the number field you want to sort, and p_dir is the direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think on this solution, isn't pretty but should work.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb8ff/14)**

Create a new column for each of your fields with the order on it.

```
SELECT CASE 1
          WHEN 1 THEN id 
          WHEN 2 THEN created_at
          WHEN 3 THEN scomment
       END as field_name 
FROM  (       
      SELECT I.id, I.rid, 
             C.created_at, C.rcreated_at,
             S.scomment, S.rscomment       
      FROM (
            SELECT t.id, 
                   @rowid := @rowid + 1 AS rid
            FROM test t, 
                   (SELECT @rowid := 0) r
            ORDER BY t.id     
           ) I   -- add sort column for id
      JOIN (     
            SELECT t.id, created_at,
                   @rowcreated_at := @rowcreated_at + 1 AS rcreated_at
            FROM test t, 
                   (SELECT @rowcreated_at := 0) r
            ORDER BY t.created_at    
           ) C  -- add sort column for created_at
        ON I.id = C.id
      JOIN (  
            SELECT t.id, scomment,
                   @rowscomment := @rowscomment + 1 AS rscomment
            FROM test t, 
                   (SELECT @rowscomment := 0) r
            ORDER BY t.scomment   
           ) S  -- add sort column for scomment
         ON I.id = S.id
     ) T
ORDER BY CASE 1
          WHEN 1 THEN rid 
          WHEN 2 THEN rcreated_at
          WHEN 3 THEN rscomment
       END
```

Comment: I include the fiddle